# rosbuild_add_executable. Where does it save this?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I used the command

```
rosbuild_add_executable(main_ParseStringCommand ${GUIA_SOURCE_FILES} ${GUIA_HEADER_FILES})
```

to my CMakeLists.txt.

I performed the:

```
$rosmake package_name
```

and ran the node by:

```
$rosrun package_name main_ParseStringCommand
```

I then changed the rosbuild_add_executable in my CMakeLists.txt to:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(main_ParseString ${GUIA_SOURCE_FILES} ${GUIA_HEADER_FILES})
```

and did:
$rosmake package_name

Now, I can run the node by:

```
$rosrun package_name main_ParseString
```

but I can still run it by:

```
$rosrun package_name main_ParseStringCommand
```

Why is this the case and how can I stop this from happening?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108121/rosbuild_add_executable.-where-does-it-save-this?/) by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2013-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't save anything AFAIK, rosmake just creates the executable. When you change the name of the executable it creates another one without deleting the old one.

If you want to stop this from happening, you can use the following command

```
rosmake --pre-clean
```

Inside your package if you list the executables with `ls -l` command, you can verify their creation time.

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2013-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-12-08**:
rosmake --pre-clean did not work but the ls -l command helped me to find where the executables are stored (in the bin folder). I just manually deleted the executables I no longer needed. Thanks!

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2013-12-08**:
Oh sorry for that. Now I wonder why it didn't work:) `--pre-clean` option makes rosmake call `make clean` first and I'd expect it to delete previously created executables. http://wiki.ros.org/rosmake#Usage
By the way, is it a cpp package? Could you also please specify the ros distro you are using?

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-12-08**:
Its strange. I watch the bin file where the executables get created and it still retains the old executables. Its okay, I will just do the manual way of removing them (its faster also XD)

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-12-08**:
I am using row fuerte and I tried the command: rosmake --pre-clean package_name. It is also a cpp package.

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2013-12-08**:
Yeah, it is strange indeed. When I do the same in similar conditions, it works for me. Anyhow, I'm glad you solved the problem.